# Can't find my "Find in Files" window in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, I can't seem to find my "Find in Files" modal window.  When I type cntrl+shift+f or go to Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files, visual studio appears to recognize the command, I just cannot see the window.  Is there a way I can reset my visual studio settings so that I can see this window again?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Window->Reset Window Layout` should revert to the default layout.

If you have exported your settings previously (before you lost the Find in Files window), you can re-import those settings as well. That's found under the Tools menu. You can clear 'All Settings' and select `General Settings->Window Layouts` only, if you want.

Comment: Definitely export those settings once you get them the way you like--saves you a ton of trouble later.

Answer (score 43):

Activate it (Ctrl+Shift+F), then with the mouse select `Window->Dock`.  It docked it above my Output window and made it visible again.

Weirdly, when I did `Window->Reset Window Layout`, it reset everything, but did not show that window or make it show up when I chose `Find in Files`.

Comment: Activate it (Ctrl+Shift+F), then with the mouse select Window->Dock worked for me in VS2017

Comment: My experience just now using VS 2019 and an older solution from a Github repo was exactly as described here, but the _results_ window, which is separate, required that I also do the same thing. I ended up docking the results window to the bottom of the floating Find in Files window after undocking and floating the results window and doing another Ctrl-Shift-F to bring the find window back.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple monitors check if it opened there. Especially if you have your laptop lid closed. The monitor could still be active.

Answer (score 2):

Activate it (Click the Find in Files shortcut which is located at top position of V.S. application), then with the mouse select Window->Dock. It docked it below my Output window and made it visible again. My visual studio is 2015.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer of the most popular answer 2 years later.

Answer (score 1):

In case of windows hidden behind screen border, its also useful to press **Left Alt + Space** to show window popup menu. Then it is possible to select **Move** action and move window to visible area using arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio Mac, I had to close all files (right click file tab > close all files), then relaunch a file and then it worked.